# How to prevent the focus on textInput while scrolling on react-native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

While scrolling on the textinput, the textInput(multiline) is focused automatically on react-native. But on iOS default app, it doesn't focus automatically even though the textinput is scrolled.